# Jest with typescript + lambda functions + lambda layers (AWS)

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

I have an issue with importing modules for my jest tests in a setup containing lambdas, lambda layers and tests. The file structure is as following:

```
backend/
├─ jest.config.js
├─ package.json
├─ babel.config.js
├─ layers/
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ aws_handler/
├─ lambdas/
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ some_lambda/
│  │  ├─ index.ts
├─ tests/
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  ├─ some_lambda.test.ts
```

When I run `npm test` I get the following error: `Cannot find module '@libs/aws' or its corresponding type declarations`.

So, when I don't test it works. In `lambdas/some_lambda/index.ts` I import a layer the following way:

```
import { lambda } from '@libs/aws';
```

and in the `lambdas/tsconfig.json` I specify the relative path to the layer

```
"baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
      "@libs/aws": [
        "../lambda_layers/aws_handler"
      ],
    }
```

So, when running the lambda it can find the `@libs/aws` module but not when testing. Ok, so far so "good".

Somewhere in `jest.config.js` and/or `package.json` I need to specify where to find this module, but I struggle doing so. Can the `jest.config.js` somehow inherit or look at the `lambdas/tsconfig.json` file?

For example I read somewhere that adding this to `package.json` would help

```
"jest": {
    ...
    "rootDir": "./",
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

or in `jest.config.js` I should specify `moduleDirectories` etc. Does anyone have a similar setup that can tell me how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to config [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) for jest the same as what you did at tsconfig.js paths.

If you use `ts-jest` as a transformer, use their helper.

`jest.config.js`

```js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./lambdas/tsconfig');


module.exports = {
  // [...]
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
}
...
```

Or you can do it without a helper:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@libs/aws/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lambda_layers/aws_handler/$1'
  },
```

Comment: Awesome, this solution saved me 2 days worth of efforts spent already debugging.